# Python write mutiple array value into csv

Tags: python

with my code, i read the values of JSON data and insert into array

```
def retrive_json():
    with open('t_v1.json') as json_data:
        d = json.load(json_data)
    array = []
    for i in d['ride']:
        origin_lat = i['origin']['lat']
        origin_lng = i['origin']['lng']
        destination_lat = i['destination']['lat']
        destination_lng = i['destination']['lng']
        array.append([origin_lat,origin_lng,destination_lat,destination_lng])

    return array
```

the result array is this :

```
[[39.72417, -104.99984, 39.77446, -104.9379], [39.77481, -104.93618, 39.6984, -104.9652]]
```

how i can write each element of each array into specific field in csv?
i have try in this way:

```
wrt = csv.writer(open(t_.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',',lineterminator='\n')
for x in jjson:
    wrt.writerow([x])
```

but the value of each array are store all in one field
How can solved it and write each in a field?

this is my json file:

```
{
"ride":[
  {
     "origin":{
        "lat":39.72417,
        "lng":-104.99984,
        "eta_seconds":null,
        "address":""
     },
     "destination":{
        "lat":39.77446,
        "lng":-104.9379,
        "eta_seconds":null,
        "address":null
     }
  },
  {
     "origin":{
        "lat":39.77481,
        "lng":-104.93618,
        "eta_seconds":null,
        "address":"10 Albion Street"
     },
     "destination":{
        "lat":39.6984,
        "lng":-104.9652,
        "eta_seconds":null,
        "address":null
     }
  }
]
}
```

Comment: how about sharing the input array? I'd really recommend using the Pandas library for doing these operations.

Comment: the array input is the second code posted in my question

Comment: shouldn't it be just wrt.writerow(x), but if you share a sample from your json data I could show you how to do it with pandas.

Comment: Assuming that jjson is list of lists and using pandas `df = pd.DataFrame(jjson)` and `df.to_csv(r"c:\temp.csv")`. Note you will get the default indexes in the csv file as well.

Comment: i have change my post and i have attach the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we have this:

```
jsonstring = """{
    "ride":[
      {
         "origin":{
            "lat":39.72417,
            "lng":-104.99984,
            "eta_seconds":null,
            "address":""
         },
         "destination":{
            "lat":39.77446,
            "lng":-104.9379,
            "eta_seconds":null,
            "address":null
         }
      },
      {
         "origin":{
            "lat":39.77481,
            "lng":-104.93618,
            "eta_seconds":null,
            "address":"10 Albion Street"
         },
         "destination":{
            "lat":39.6984,
            "lng":-104.9652,
            "eta_seconds":null,
            "address":null
         }
      }
    ]
    }"""
```

Here is a pandas solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

# Load json to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(jsonstring)["ride"])
# Create the new columns
df["o1"] = df["origin"].apply(lambda x: x["lat"])
df["o2"] = df["origin"].apply(lambda x: x["lng"])
df["d1"] = df["destination"].apply(lambda x: x["lat"])
df["d2"] = df["destination"].apply(lambda x: x["lng"])

#export
print(df.iloc[:,2:].to_csv(index=False, header=True))
#use below for file
#df.iloc[:,2:].to_csv("output.csv", index=False, header=True)
```

Returns:

```
o1,o2,d1,d2
39.72417,-104.99984,39.77446,-104.9379
39.77481,-104.93618,39.6984,-104.9652
```

Condensed answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('data.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
df = pd.DataFrame(d["ride"])
df["o1"],df["o2"] = zip(*df["origin"].apply(lambda x: (x["lat"],x["lng"])))
df["d1"],df["d2"] = zip(*df["destination"].apply(lambda x: (x["lat"],x["lng"])))
df.iloc[:,2:].to_csv("t_.csv",index=False,header=False)
```

Or, maybe the most readable solution:

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
open('data.json') as json_data:
    d = json.load(json_data)
df = json_normalize(d["ride"])
cols = ["origin.lat","origin.lng","destination.lat","destination.lng"]
df[cols].to_csv("output.csv",index=False,header=False)
```

Comment: your code is correct and good, but i have notice that if i read the json by request response i have this error: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: @APPGIS Are u using requests library? In that case post your link if possible.Normally you have to work with json.dump(s) or json.load(s). You can also get a json directly by doing data = requests.get(url).json()

Comment: yes, i get a json by get request using requests module, ut i have fix. Thanks for your help

Comment: @APPGIS curious though, which "solution" did you pick?

Comment: I have use your first solution, but i have see that also the solution posted by tkhurana96 is correct., so i have check as correct both solutions

Comment: @APPGIS I meant which one of the 3 I posted you found most readable. Thank you for your time:

Comment: the first of 3 solution

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
import json
import csv

def retrive_json():
    with open('data.json') as json_data:
        d = json.load(json_data)
    array = []
    for i in d['ride']:
        origin_lat = i['origin']['lat']
        origin_lng = i['origin']['lng']
        destination_lat = i['destination']['lat']
        destination_lng = i['destination']['lng']
        array.append([origin_lat,origin_lng,destination_lat,destination_lng])

    return array



res = retrive_json()

csv_cols = ["orgin_lat", "origin_lng", "dest_lat", "dest_lng"]

with open("output_csv.csv", 'w') as out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out, fieldnames=csv_cols)

    writer.writeheader()
    for each_list in res:
        d = dict(zip(csv_cols,each_list))
        writer.writerow(d)
```

Output csv generated is:

```
orgin_lat,origin_lng,dest_lat,dest_lng
39.72417,-104.99984,39.77446,-104.9379
39.77481,-104.93618,39.6984,-104.9652
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like you've got an array of arrays and you want the individual elements. Therefore you'll want to use a nested `for` loop. Your current `for` loop is getting each array, to then split up each array into it's elements you'll want to loop through those. I'd suggest something like this:

```
for x in jjson:
    for y in x:
        wrt.writerow([y])
```

Obviously you might want to update your bracketing etc this is just me giving you an idea of how to solve your issue.

Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 0):

Why the `csv`-Library?

```
array = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]]

with open('test.csv', 'w') as csv_file :
    csv_file.write("# Header Info\n" \
                   "# Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4\n")   # The header might be optional

    for row in array :
         csv_file.write(",".join(row) + "\n")
```